# Opening Button to open form based on combo box selection

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I currently have a MS Access database of members.

I have a form that has a combo box which is populated with just the first and last names of members. (using a test database for now)

What im struggling with is how do i create a button that opens another form i have created but using the selection in the dropdown box to populate the fields in the newly opened form.

When a user from the dropdown box is selected an open is clicked i want it to open the profile form populated with their details.

pictures and access files can be found on my ftp server:

ftp://ftp.legends-gym.co.uk
User: ftpuser@legends-gym.co.uk
Pass: ftpuser

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't access ftp site from work so can't see what you've got thus far however, the key bits you want to look at here are:

1. Add a button to the form and the On Click Event to open your profile form. Something along the lines of `docmd.openform "frmProfile", acNormal`
2. You need something to pass the member you've selected in the combo box to the profile form. One way might be to use OpenArgs so have a look at that
3. You then could use the passed variable in OpenArgs to select the data you want to fill out your profile form.

EDIT...

OK, I've had a look at the file now. Here is what you need to do to fix your problems (and a couple of extra bits which aren't causing an issue but will improve the look and feel).

1. On the Format of the Home form and the Member Search form, set `Navigation Buttons` and `Record Selector` to false. - This removes the unnecessary elements for a "single" form, you're not looking at records.
2. On the member search form, remove the binding to the members table. - You don't need to bind this form, as the recordsource of the combo is pulling the data required separately. if you look at your form before you change it, you'll notice you've got 1 of 10 records...
3. Also, remove the filter criteria and set filter on load to No - You were filtering the wrong form.
4. On the combo box, remove the after update event. - I'm not sure what that was trying to do but its completely unnecessary.
5. On the command button, add an onclick event which has the following code `DoCmd.OpenForm "Profile", acNormal, , "ID = " & Me.Combo361 & ""`
6. Save everything and enjoy. :)

You weren't far wrong with the filter, but it's actually a WHERE clause when opening another form - sorry, my bad misdirection. What you were doing was filtering the original form - ie the member search form. Also, you don't need to put ' quotes around the ID, it's a number not a string.

If you have problems I can probably host this fixed version somewhere for you to download.

Comment: Thanks for this, the button now opens the form and the form has data, but not the data that should be in there, its just filling it in with the first entry in the DB

Comment: That's because your recordsource is not being filtered in anyway. That is what the openargs are for, to pass the record ID to be filtered for.

Comment: i had a read about the open args, but still dont fully understand it  how do i get it to pass the ID to the form?

Comment: You identify the record you want from the combo box. You don't need the openargs if it's a bound fprm, you just need to filter for that particular record. In the openform command, there's a parameter for filter. Use that to say something like `"Customer=" & me.ComboBox`

Comment: still unable to get it to work, i must be missing something, all i need is the value from the combo box passed to a search or filter when the button is clicked to open a form.? have updated the FTP server with the latest file. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, I have my laptop with me today so I'll download it at lunch and have a look for you.

Comment: OK, I have the file. There are a number of issues with it even at this stage. I'm getting a Data Type Mismatch error even opening the search form, which I'm presuming is the one you want to use. Additionally, you've got record selectors enabled and your form is bound to the member table when it should be the combo box record source that's bound and the form left unbound. Lastly there's no onclick event for the button underneath the combo box. This is not going to do anything at all. I can sort all this out for you no drama's though.

Comment: Working - Thanks alot your help is appreciated.